# Why $\frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}\sim N(0,I)? $

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, linear

I try to prove one result from linear regression model as follows.

> Let $\beta_j$ denote the $j$th element of $\beta$ and $A_{ii}^{-1}$ the $i$th diagonal element of $A^{-1}$. Then we have
> $$\frac{\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}\hat{\sigma}^2}}\sim t_{n-p}
> $$
> where
> $$
> \hat{{\sigma}^2}=\frac{1}{n-p}(Y-\hat{Y})^T(Y-\hat{Y})$$

Indeed, $\hat{\beta}-\beta\sim N(0, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})$ and is independent of $\hat{\sigma}^2$. Then
$$\frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta}{\hat{\sigma}}\sim\frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2\chi^2_{n-p}}{n-p}}}\sim \frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{\frac{\chi^2_{n-p}}{n-p}}}
$$

But I am confused that why
$$
\frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}\sim N(0,I)?
$$
Isn't it divided by $\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}}$?

Comment: $$\frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}\sim N(0,I)$$ This makes no sense to me. In the numerator and right hand side you have a matrix as variance. Do you refer to a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)?

Comment: You have mixed up vectors and scalars.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus But if we want to show that is t-distribution, we need to the numerator is standard normal.

Comment: We do not "divide" by a matrix, we multiply by its inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't it divided by $\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}}$?

$\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}}$ is not a single number.

This is because $X$ is a $n$ by $p$ matrix and $X^T X$ will be a $p$ by $p$ matrix of which you need the $j$-th diagonal element.

> But I am confused that why $$ \frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}\sim N(0,I)?$$

This is not the case.

- Yes, you do have that each individual $\hat\beta_j - \beta_j$ is normal distributed
- But no, the multivariate case does not hold. The scaled $\hat\beta_j - \beta_j$ will be correlated.

In addition the expression $$\frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}$$ does not seem quite right. The arithmetics/operation, how you divide the multivariate normal distribution, is not very clear and defined.

Comment: My question is that how to show that $\frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}\sim N(0,I)? $

Comment: @quasAliki I responded to your sentence that ended in a question mark. You can not divide by the product $X^TX$ because it is a matrix.

Comment: Regarding your question why we have $$\frac{N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}}}\sim N(0,I)?$$ The answer is that we do not have this. The expression makes no sense. Or at least for me it is unclear what you mean by the expression $N(0, (X^TX)^{-1})$ which is not a typical expression.

Comment: If not, how to prove that $\frac{\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j}{\sqrt{(X^TX)^{-1}_{jj}\hat{\sigma}^2}}\sim t_{n-p}
$?

Comment: @quasAliki in your question you use $$\hat{\beta}-\beta\sim N(0, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})$$ that is a multivariate distribution. For the derivation/proof you can use the distribution of only the $j$-th component of that distribution $$\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j \sim N(0, \sigma^2(X^TX)_{jj}^{-1})$$

Comment: Thanks. I still have a question. Why are all off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix of $\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j$ equal $0$? I mean $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is a p*p matrix. So where are the others off-diagonal elements of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @quasAliki the off-diagonal elements are not equal to 0 in general. That is only the case when the columns in $X$ are perpendicular vectors.

Comment: @quasAliki I could give a more in-depth explanation, but for this it would be useful if you give more background about this problem. Then I can adapt the explanation better to your level and background. Where does this occur? Are you studying some book for a course, or are you learning this for some other reason (in which field are you)?

Comment: Thanks. I am a graduate student and I learn it by myself. I just want to mark sure that $\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_i\sim N(0, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}_{ji})$, right?